# How do you connect a GtkTreeVew and a GtkListStore?

Tags: c, model, gtk

How do you connect a GtkTreeVew and a GtkListStore?

My TreeView shows the ListStore's data fine, but won't update the ListStore when the user changes a value in one of the cellrenderer widgets. The widgets behave normally but when they lose focus the value returns to normal.

Would I have to write signal handlers for every cell I make or is there some setting I should be setting?

I'm using glade to create these models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the only way to do this is to catch the edited signal and handle it manually. What a shame.